# Azure API Management Extractor tool from Microsoft doesnt support extracting named values with Key vault values

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-api-management

I am using [extractor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit/blob/main/src/README.md#extractor) tool from Microsoft. Recently we changed some of our named values type from secret to Key vault. However when we generate extractor tool it deletes that named values and ignore it. Is there any way to fix this so that we can generate all types of named values?
See the arm template code change screenshot for the named value which is not identified by tool which contains key vault secret
[image]

Comment: you probably wanna open an issue on their github repo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using old extractor tool. At that time there was no support for Named values with Key vault hence it was ignoring KV from portal. Now I have updated extractor tool and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Extractor tool might not handle changes as expected. If the Extractor tool does not work properly, you need to manually update the produced ARM templates after using the tool.

Instead of above, you can manage APIM configuration using
`Azure PowerShell or CLI`.

I tried updated named value to secret using PowerShell and it worked as shown.

```
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "xxxxxx" -ServiceName "xxxxx"
Set-AzApiManagementNamedValue -Context $apimContext -NamedValueId "Property12" -Secret $True -PassThru
```

[image]

Reference: [`Set-AzApiManagementNamedValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagementnamedvalue?view=azps-10.2.0#code-try-2) PowerShell command.

*If this doesn't work for you, raise a support request for the extractor tool functionality.*

Comment: I had to update the extractor tool code from GIThub and it worked. The code we were using was quite old by then, namedvalues with Key vault Secret were not supported.